# How do I screencap another Xorg display?

Tags: linux, xorg, x11, x-server

I started another X session from my current one like so:

```
xinit xterm -- :128
```

An X session starts in display `:128`, `xterm` gets run in it and everything is fine.

I switched back to screen `:0` (the default), though, and tried to `screencap` the new display:

```
$ xwd -root -screen -out screencap.xwd -display :128
```

and the resulting file was just a big black rectangle. I also tried with imagemagick `import`, to no avail. What is going wrong?

Comment: Try using `scrot`. Tested here, seems to work.

Comment: How do you screencap a different display (other than the current) using scrot? I can't find it in the man page

Comment: `DISPLAY=<display> scrot`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like [`scrot`](http://freecode.com/projects/scrot) is able to do it, tested with:

```
xinit thunar -- :128
DISPLAY=:128 scrot
```

gave me a correct screenshot.

(but unfortunately, scrot has been unmaintained for quite a while)

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that x displays blank the screen and stop redrawing once their tty loses focus, with the intention of conserving CPU time and RAM. It doesn't look like there is a way to disable this functionality.

`Xvfb`, 'X Virtual Framebuffer' is a special implementation that does not feature this behavior as part of it's design and purpose.

Instead of initiating a new 'normal' xsession, I ran the client software in a virtual framebuffer:

```
xvfb-run <client software> --server-args="-screen 0 [width]x[height]x[bitdepth]"
```

and screencapped like this:

```
xwd -root -d :99 # (the default for xvfb)
```

Note that this display may be harder for the user to get at since it's not tied to a terminal.